# Validation of input - Numbers vs. Letters

Tags: c#, validation

I am creating a short C# console program that will ask 10 addition questions using random numbers from 0-10.  Then it tells the user how many correct or incorrect answers they had.  I am trying to find a way to validate that my user input is a number and not a letter.  I am posting the code I have created so far, but could use some help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int input;
            int correct = 0;
            int incorrect = 0;
            int questions = 10;
            int[] solutions = new int[21];
            int[] answers = new int[21];
            int[] number1 = new int[21];
            int[] number2 = new int[21]; 

            Random number = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("  This is a test of your basic addition skills. ");
            Console.WriteLine("  Please answer the random addition question below ");
            Console.WriteLine("  with a number from 1 - 20 and press enter to get the");
            Console.WriteLine("  next of 10 questions.  At the end of the questions");
            Console.WriteLine("  your results will be calculated and presented to you.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            while (i < questions)
            {
                number1[i] = number.Next(0, 10);
                number2[i] = number.Next(0,10);
                solutions[i] = (number1[i] + number2[i]);

                //Console.WriteLine("{0} +  {1} =  {2}", number1[i], number2[i],solutions[i]);  

                Console.Write("  {0} +  {1} =  ", number1[i], number2[i]);

                answers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // original code      

                //input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                //if (input > 0 && input <21)
                //{
                //   Console.WriteLine("YOur answer is: {0}", input);
                //}
                //else
                //Console.WriteLine("YOur answer is not valid");

                if (solutions[i] == answers[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Correct");
                    correct++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Your answer is incorrect, the correct answer is {0}", solutions[i]);
                    incorrect++;

                }
                //Console.WriteLine("{0}", answers[i]);

                //int sum = numberone + numbertwo;
                //answers[sum]++;
                i++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("The number correct is: {0}, The number incorrect is: {1}", correct, incorrect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my snippet so you can literally replace your ReadLine() section with it now.

Answer (score 14):

Use int.TryParse() like:

```
bool isNumber=false;
int number;
while (!isNumber)
{
  string txt = Console.ReadLine();
  if (!int.TryParse(txt, out number))
  {
    // not a number, handle it
    Console.WriteLine("This is not a number, enter a number. For real now.");
  }
  else
  {
    // use number
    answers[i] = number;
    isNumber = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice and direct, no extra exceptions floating around

Comment: Why not just use Int32.TryParse(String, Int32) instead of doing it twice?

Comment: need an out parameter - won't compile
and int number will only be accessible from inside the else scope

Comment: It just left blank positions in the answers array

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
answers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // original code
```

Use:

```
int input;
bool validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
if (!validInput || input < 0 && input > 20)
    <throw exception or display some error message here...>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to recursively ask for a correct input, this is how you can do it:

```
int input;
bool validInput = false;

while (!validInput)
{
    validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
    if (!validInput || input < 0 && input > 20)
    {
        validInput = false; // We need to set this again to false if the input is not between 0 & 20!
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 0 and 20");
    }
}
```

Comment: Working with your solution, but I also want to reprompt the user to reenter a valid answer, should I use a while loop instead of an if? and can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
int iResult = int.MinValue;
bool bParsed = int.TryParse("xyz", out iResult);
```

TryParse will not throw an exception.

However, you can use Convert.ToInt32() as well if needed but that will throw an exception on bad data.

Comment: No need to initialize iResult as it is an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answers[i]) && answers[i] > 0 && ...)
{ 
    ...
}
else
{
   // invalid answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to fill all positions of your array:

```
int result;
bool isInt = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
if (!isInt) {
  Console.WriteLine("Your input is not an integer number.");
  continue;
}

answers[i] = result;
```

Comment: I also want to prompt the user to reenter a number

Comment: Eric, simply put a while (validNumber) around the ReadLine with a boolean flag 'validNumber' which you set to true if valid, and to false outside of the while loop.